# Multiprocessing In Terminal Node.js Application

Tags: python, node.js, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have a Node.js application that will be run in the command line. I need to run multiple instances of my code within the same command line instance. I am basically looking for a processing pools (python) equivalent in node.js.

Comment: I think cluster is what you are looking for https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stack Overflow! I would take a really hard look at this: https://github.com/Microsoft/napajs which will take multiple V8 isolates and does all the communicating between them!

Let me know if this works for you.